# How do I add a postinst file to my debian package?

Tags: debian, packaging

I'm trying to add a 'postinst' script to my debian package to clean up something a previous version may have left behind.

I've simply created a 'postinst' file in the debian/ directory, but the file is not present in the .deb file.

The permissions:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 kp kp 354 Sep 16 20:00 postinst*
```

The content:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
set -x

...
```

Comment: can you post the file permissions for the postinst file and the contents of postinst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the `postinst` file (and other similar files) to the package staging directory. If you use `dh_make`, this is performed by `dh_installdeb`, which is of course included in `dh install`. If you're doing everything manually. copy the file to `debian/tmp/DEBIAN/` where `debian/tmp` is the staging directory.

Comment: I didn't have the 'dh_installdeb' in my debian/rules file.